# Pandas list of dict in multiple excel sheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have multiple lists of dict that converge to one list of dict to an excel file. The idea is to make an excel sheet for each dict, key(web1, web2), name and have the correct info in each sheet.
The problem of the code below is that it make a excel file of one sheet.
Any idea on how should I do it?

```
import pandas as pd

web1 = [{
        'country': 'NL',
        'id': '56655',
        'title': 'some 1',
        'date': 'today',
        'description': 'something else here',
        'web': 'http://'
        },
        {
        'country': 'IE',
        'jobid': '45862',
        'title': 'some 2',
        'date': 'today',
        'description': 'something else here',
        'web': 'http://'
        }]

web2 = [{
        'country': 'IT',
        'id': '77878',
        'title': 'some 3',
        'date': 'today',
        'description': 'something else here',
        'web': 'http://'
        },
        {
        'country': 'NE',
        'id': '45862',
        'title': 'some 4',
        'date': 'today',
        'description': 'something else here',
        'web': 'http://'
        }]

data =[{
    'website1': web1
    },
    {
    'website1': web2
    }]


for x in data:
    z = str(*x).capitalize()
    for y in  x.values():
        cx = pd.DataFrame(y, columns = ['country', 'title', 'date', 'id', 'web','description'])
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx')
        cx.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f'{z}')

        workbook = writer.book
        worksheet = writer.sheets[f'{z}']
        align_r = workbook.add_format({'align': 'right'})
        bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
        color_format = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'green'})
        condi_color = worksheet.conditional_format('G:G', {
                                            'type': 'text',
                                            'criteria': 'containing',
                                            'value': 'red',
                                            'format': color_format})
        # set column spacing, format
        worksheet.set_column('A:A', 3)
        worksheet.set_column('B:B', 2, bold)
        worksheet.set_column('C:C', 40, bold)
        worksheet.set_column('D:D', 10, align_r)
        worksheet.set_column('G:G')


writer.save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pandas` has an `ExcelWriter` helper, it's right in the docs.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

```
>>> writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
>>> df1.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
>>> df2.to_excel(writer,'Sheet2')
>>> writer.save()
```

So, each dict becomes a df with `pd.DataFrame(webN)` and then you call the df with the writer as shown in lines 2 and 3 above.

Edit:

To iterate through your list of dicts, you could write:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
for i in range(len(list_of_dicts)):
    df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts[i]) # Construct the dataframe
    df.to_excel(writer, "Sheet{}".format(i + 1))
```

Depending on the data you might want to construct the dataframe with [from_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html)

Comment: Beside writing `pd.DataFrame(webN)` for each dict there is no other way to do it? I could have 10+ webN dict